# DataStax Studio : Update an integer property of node

Tags: database, datastax, gremlin, datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph

we have a vertex which has a property of type int and when I try to update that property for that node like

```
g.V().hasLabel("business").hasNot("authenticityScore").properties("authenticityScore",0).iterate()
```

This query is not updating the record.

Is there any typecast I need to take care of while updating an int value from Datastax studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That syntax is not correct. The `properties()` step gets a list of properties from the graph element (e.g. Vertex), but `property()` sets a property key and value, therefore your traversal should be written as:

```
g.V().hasLabel("business").hasNot("authenticityScore").
  property("authenticityScore",0).iterate()
```